# see android logcat without eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

I need my friends to see my app's log without installing eclipse. 
What is the easiest/fastest way to make them see the logs from my app? Do they just need to install the android-sdk and run monitor.bat?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use DDMS.bat (or Monitor.bat) inside of the Android SDK

Additionally, you could install a logging app from the Play Store, such as [aLogCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.jtb.alogcat&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsIm9yZy5qdGIuYWxvZ2NhdCJd).

Comment: After downloading the SDK do they need to set any environment variable or other things? Or is just download sdk, run ddms and that's all?

Comment: i don't like aLogcat, short buffer and poor filter management

Comment: @DiegoLucaccini The only thing should need are USB drivers for their phone. If they have trouble with that, you can always install (and uninstall after it adds the correct drivers) PDANet http://junefabrics.com/android/ which is bundled with most drivers for most phones

Comment: Hahaha well you said "i want to see logcat", you didn't say you needed filtering and such!

Comment: Do note that apps like aLogcat will not work in the latest version of JellyBean unless it's installed as a system app (requires root)

Comment: Hmmm I just installed it with no problems (I had CatLog installed and that works too)

Comment: @dmon Android 4.2 or 4.1? 4.2 is where they changed the permissions of reading logs

Answer (score 2):

- You can use aLogCat as Bryan has pointed out.
- If you have the sdk installed, you can run `adb logcat` from terminal.